# Can't display HTML because of markdown

Tags: html, syntax-highlighting, markdown, google-code-prettify

So I'm using AnchorCMS and using Google code prettify. All languages but HTML work. I've asked this before and I was told to use `&lt;` and `&gt;` and so fourth. So I used it, but when I save the post its rendered back into HTML, so the HTML which I'm trying to display doesn't show. [Here's](http://colourity.com/posts/html-stuff) what I'm talking about. That's when I try displauing `<!DOCTYPE html>` and [here's](http://colourity.com/posts/arrays-in-php) what it should look like with the code highlighting. Is there a way I can disable markdown maybe on certain posts?

Comment: When I go to [the html link](http://colourity.com/posts/html-stuff) and 'inspect element', there is nothing in the `<code></code>` block. But when I add formatted HTML betweeon the `<code></code>` blocks (using my browser tools), it shows up. Can you post what you are trying to insert into the code block? Are you using `&lt;`, `&gt;` or `<` and `>`?

Comment: I'm using `&lt;` and `&gt;`, but when I save the post its turns into `<` and `>` @adilapapaya

Comment: one thing that's just odd to me is that it's not even syntax highlighting the php or css code but rather just printing it our like a regular code block. I'm wondering if there's an error in the way you're applying it. Maybe try removing the `class='lang-html'` from the `code` blocks and just using straight-up `<code></code>` to see if it shows up?

Comment: Just got rid of it. But it still doesn't show @adilapapaya

Comment: hmm, ok one more thing you can try is to add html markup to a php code block. E.g. add a `<div>something something</div>` to one of the php code blocks at http://colourity.com/posts/arrays-in-php and see if it shows up. It does when I do it from the browser but not when you load it directly into the html so I think the script must be messing up somewhere. I'm just not sure where.

Comment: The block still shows, but the text under it gets smaller. And when I try the page i'm having issues with, nothing changes. @adilapapaya